# Pandas: transforming the DataFrameGroupBy object to desired format

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                   'code' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                             'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                   'colour': ['black', 'white','white','white',
                           'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
                   'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','code','colour','amount'])
```

**I want to be able to group the `id`s by `code` and `colour` and then sort them with respect to `amount`.** I know how to `groupby()`:

```
df.groupby(['code','colour']).head(5)
                id   code colour    amount
code  colour                              
one   black  0   1    one  black -0.117307
      white  1   2    one  white  1.653216
             6   7    one  white  0.817205
three black  5   6  three  black  0.567162
      white  3   4  three  white  0.579074
two   black  4   5    two  black -1.683988
      white  2   3    two  white -0.457722
             7   8    two  white -1.277020
```

However, my desired output is as below, where I have two columns: 1.`code/colour`contains the key strings and 2.`id:amount` contains `id` - `amount` tuples sorted in descending order wrt `amount`:

```
code/colour  id:amount
one/black    {1:-0.117307}
one/white    {2:1.653216, 7:0.817205}
three/black  {6:0.567162}
three/white  {4:0.579074}
two/black    {5:-1.683988}
two/white    {3:-0.457722, 8:-1.277020}
```

How can I transform the `DataFrameGroupBy` object displayed above to my desired format? Or, shall I not use `groupby()` in the first place?

**EDIT:**
Although not in the specified format, the code below kind of gives me the functionality I want:

```
groups = dict(list(df.groupby(['code','colour'])))
groups['one','white']
   id code colour    amount
1   2  one  white  1.331766
6   7  one  white  0.808739
```

How can I reduce the groups to only include the `id` and `amount` column?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, groupby code and colour and then apply a customized function to format id and amount:

```
df = df.groupby(['code', 'colour']).apply(lambda x:x.set_index('id').to_dict('dict')['amount'])
```

And then modify the index:

```
df.index = ['/'.join(i) for i in df.index]
```

It will return a series, you can convert it back to DataFrame by:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Finally, add the column names by:

```
df.columns=['code/colour','id:amount']
```

Result:

```
In [105]: df
Out[105]: 
   code/colour                               id:amount
0    one/black                     {1: 0.392264412544}
1    one/white  {2: 2.13950686015, 7: -0.393002947047}
2  three/black                      {6: -2.0766612539}
3  three/white                     {4: -1.18058561325}
4    two/black                     {5: -1.51959565941}
5    two/white  {8: -1.7659863039, 3: -0.595666853895}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems useful. I was searching on the website and found another solution that provides a similar functionality (although not in the exact format specified) with using `dict(list(df.groupby(['code','colour'])))`. The only undesirable thing is that this unnecessarily stores all columns. Is there a way to make this store only the `id` and `amount` columns? I added this to my question under **EDIT**

Comment: What functionality do you what? A dictionary map the code,colour pair to a dataframe contains id and amount?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an "ugly" way of doing this. First things first- your desired output will not play so well within Pandas since `dict` is unhashable; so you may lose the real benefit!

```
od = OrderedDict()
for name, group in df.groupby(['code', 'colour']):
    # Convert the group to a dict
    temp = group[['id', 'amount']].sort(['amount'], ascending=[0]).to_dict()
    # Extract id:amount
    temp2 = {temp['id'][key]: temp['amount'][key] for key in temp['amount'].iterkeys()}
    od["%s/%s" % (name)] = temp2
```

This is only a start! Not exactly what you are looking for.